# Getting the real destination link from google search

Tags: google-search, links

Steps to reproduce:

1. Search for "wavetek4.pdf" via  [Google search: wavetek4.pdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=wavetek4.pdf&hl=en&lr=lang_en).
2. Look in the entry. Right mouse click on the link and it goes to Google. Not to the real site.
3. Click on Share button to the right, and it pops up something to share to Google+, but I am looking for the actual link to the real PDF document there.

Just copying and pasting from the text given in the search result is not the answer because this is what I see:

www.physique.ens-cachan.fr/laboratoire/.../wavetek4.pdf

Notice the "..." there which foils the copy-and-paste solution.

[Using a greasemonkey script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14123/14529) is also not a viable answer because I shouldn't have to install a plugin just to get this basic URL.

[Right click some empty space...](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/40834/14529) is also not a solution as it does not seem to work on the [above search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wavetek4.pdf&hl=en&lr=lang_en).

EDIT: No, I'm not interested in PHP scripts or other scripts. Should be doable in any non-customized browser, not Firefox-, IE-, or Chrome-specific etc.

Comment: When I hover the mouse pointer over the link in the search result I see the full link `http://www.physique.ens-cachan.fr/laboratoire/materiel/fichiers/wavetek4.pdf` and I can easily right-click and 'Copy Link Location', saving the full link. Have you tried either of these methods?

Comment: @TomBrossman: The link given by 'Copy Link Location' is a link rooted at Google, not the real link I'm after.

Comment: @AlEverett: See the "Using a greasemonkey script" link in the original question that I stated was not the answer. That is a link to a specific comment in [Copy raw link found by Google search, not the one with extra redirect added](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/copy-raw-link-found-by-google-search-not-the-one-with-extra-redirect-added)

Comment: @TomBrossman: As soon as the search results appear... when you hover over the link you see the actual URL in the status bar, but as soon as you right-click the actual URL is replaced by a google redirect URL and afterwards, hovering over the link just shows the google URL in the status bar.

Comment: @bgoodr: The "right click some empty space" workaround works for me in Chrome, IE9 and Firefox. But not in Safari (Win) or Opera. In Safari you get the context menu immediately, not when releasing the mouse. In Opera (with mouse gestures disabled) the context menu simply does not show after moving the mouse to another element.

Comment: @w3d Strange that we are having different results. I am able to see and copy the direct links no problem (that's how I got the link in the first comment) . Am I misunderstanding the question or are we seeing different results in our browsers? Firefox latest in Ubuntu here, if that helps...

Comment: @TomBrossman: Maybe there is a difference on Linux? I'm currently on Windows.

Comment: I rechecked and I am still seeing the behavior which matches what @w3d stated.